# Exclude a specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, php

Anyone have any suggestions on how to edit the below to exclude 1 particular category? (ID - 1511)

Any help would be appreciated :) thanks

```
<?php
class Sinch_Tonerconfigurator_Helper_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category
{

    public function canShow($category)
     {
         if (is_int($category)) {
             $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
         }

         if (!$category->getId()) {
             return false;
         }

         if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
             return false;
         }
         if (!$category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
 //            return false;
         }

         return true;
     }

}
?>
```

```
    public function loadDropdownAction(){
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $catid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('catid', null);
        $lastlevel = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lastlevel', 0);
        if(!$catid){
            $this->getResponse()->setBody('{ "success": false, "subcategories": [] }');
            return;
        }
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
        if(!$category->hasChildren()){
            $this->getResponse()->setBody('{ "success": false, "subcategories": [] }');
            return;
        }
        $children = (Mage::getSingleton('tonerconfigurator/category')->isRootCategory($catid) ? Mage::getSingleton('tonerconfigurator/category')->getRootSubcatColl() : $category->getChildrenCategories());
        $response = array();
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['subcategories'] = array();
        foreach($children as $child){
            $childArray = array();
            $childArray['name'] = $child->getName();
            if($lastlevel){
                $childArray['URL'] = $child->getUrl();
            }else {
                $childArray['id'] = $child->getId();
            }
            $response['subcategories'][] = $childArray;
        }
        if(!empty($response['subcategories'])){
            $response['success'] = true;
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In context of your code snippet: (with code optimized)

```
 if (!$category->getId() || !$category->getIsActive() || $category->getId() == 1511 ) {
         return false;
     }

    return true
```

However, I can see you start with a ->load($category), which is most likely a model being loaded, and preceding that, I'd make the assumption you are using a collection?

If using a collection, you have better performance to simply exclude this id from the collection itself by using a collection filter as such: `->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('ne' => 1511))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've tried adding this and it doesn't seem to block the specific id from the drop down selection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  public function canShow($category)
     {
         if (is_int($category)) {
             $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
         }

    if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
         if (!$category->getId() || !$category->getIsActive() || !$category->isInRootCategoryList()  || ($category->getId() == 1511) ) {
             return false;
        }else{
        return true;
        }
    }

        return false;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, no joy though unfortunately, am I perhaps trying to edit the wrong file? my site is here: www.printcart.co.uk

Under the cartridge finder drop downs I want to eliminate the option that says 'printers' as it's a dead end if you know what I mean. Could it be in the AjaxController.php file?

Comment: yes.it AjaxController.php.. But You need find the module

Comment: Thanks, i've edited my original post to include the ajaxcontroller.php code also, not sure what you mean by find the module

In the modules file is this:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Sinch_Tonerconfigurator>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sinch_Tonerconfigurator>
     </modules>
</config>

Comment: please check  $catid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('catid', null); give cat id or not

Comment: or use Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($catid); instead of  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);

Comment: Thanks for your help,

How would this prevent ID 1511 (printers) from showing in the cartridge finder but still showing in the menu system?

Comment: just disable this  category from admin

Comment: I don't want to disable the category though, I want it to appear in the main menu but disable it from appearing in the cartridge finder

Comment: show dropdown CODE

Comment: No :) I mean I want it to appear in the menu / top menu / menu bar whatever you want to call it, but disable it in the Cartridge finder layered navigation drop down menu system -

See here(keep the blue circled bit remove it from the red circled bit):
http://imgur.com/SoGZfnG - The above code is the code for the Cartridge finder, circled in Red